# cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: xcode

I have a problem about"cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files"

and "link/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/bulid/products/debug-iphonesimulator/project.app/app" <-problem link

I want to solve this problem

but I think  I provide'S information is not Detailed

if i need solve my problem what information i need to provide?

Comment: 11 years later and i still got this when building previews. Anyone with a fix?